# Populate PHP array with data from MYSQL SELECT using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am using one of the jquery ui autocomplete functions and have a requirement to create a php array populated in a foreach loop containing results from a PDO SELECT query.

The resultant  array should look like this:

```
Array(
"result1"=>"result1",
"result2"=>"result2",   
"result3"=>"result3",
"result4"=>"result4"
"remaining results"=>"remaining results"
);
```

I tried this:

```
echo '$items = array(';
foreach($resulttags as $tag_rows)
{
$tags_display = $tag_rows['tag'];
echo '"' . $tags_display . '"=>"' . $tags_display . '",';
}
echo ");";
```

That echos out the array on the page but it does not work. I also tried this:

```
$items = array(); 
foreach($resulttags as $tag_rows)
{    
$results['"' . $tag_rows['tag'] . '"'] = '"' . $tag_rows['tag'] . '"'; 
}
```

But this results in square brackets around the array keys, and does not seem to want to work with the autocomplete.  I am assuming the downvotes are b'c I did not show what I had tried already, I posted the question on my iPhone, and am now back to my laptop.

Im thinking this shouldnt be too hard but I have tried a number of approaches that have not worked. Any suggestions? These arrays Always give me fits, have not gotten my head around them yet.

Comment: What have you tried?  We'll help you with existing code.  We won't give you something for nothing though.

Comment: You're not building a PHP array... you're building a *STRING* that could be interpreted as an array if the moon and planets are properly aligned.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling that my first try was just building a string. It is helpful to know that is not the right approach. I will continue tinkering with my other approach then.

Comment: http://php.net/array_push is what you want, and its equivalent shortcut `$var[] = ...`.

Comment: Thanks. That last downvote just seems like piling on.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just being stupid. I did this and it worked just fine:

```
$items = array();  
foreach($resulttags as $tag_rows)
{
$items[$tag_rows['tag']] = $tag_rows['tag'];
}
```

For some stupid reason I was trying to get the output from print_r to match the php code that I was trying to recreate from the autocomplete demo. Instead of getting the two outputs from print_r to match. Pretty dumb. Cost myself three downvotes too.